# Pandas reading NULL as a NaN float instead of str

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, nan

Given the file:

```
$ cat test.csv 
a,b,c,NULL,d
e,f,g,h,i
j,k,l,m,n
```

Where the 3rd column is to be treated as `str`.

When I did a string function on the column, `pandas` has read the `NULL` str as a `NaN` float:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', names=[0,1,2,3,4], dtype={0:str, 1:str, 2:str, 3:str, 4:str})

>>> df[3].apply(str.strip)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2355, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1569, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer (pandas/_libs/lib.c:66440)
TypeError: descriptor 'strip' requires a 'str' object but received a 'float'
```

To verify:

```
>>> for i in df[3]:
...    print (type(i), i)
... 
<class 'float'> nan
<class 'str'> h
<class 'str'> m
```

I've specified the `dtype` at initialization but somehow it got overriden.

**How do I force the type of a specific column to be fixed?**

**Is there a way of automatically finding these abnormal `NaN` floats and change then back to `'NULL'` string?**

Comment: BTW, is this a `pandas` bug? Or a feature?

Comment: A feature, it is ;P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For me works [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df[3] = df[3].astype(str)

for i in df[3]:
    print (type(i), i)

<class 'str'> nan
<class 'str'> h
<class 'str'> m
```

Another solution is use `keep_default_na=False` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""a,b,c,NULL,d
e,f,g,h,i
j,k,l,m,n"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp),  names=[0,1,2,3,4], keep_default_na=False)
print (df)
   0  1  2     3  4
0  a  b  c  NULL  d
1  e  f  g     h  i
2  j  k  l     m  n

for i in df[3]:
    print (type(i), i)
<class 'str'> NULL
<class 'str'> h
<class 'str'> m
```

Then is possible use `na_values` parameter if need parse `NaN` in numeric columns, but it has to be different e.g. `NA`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""a,b,c,NULL,1
e,f,g,h,2
j,k,l,m,NA"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp),  names=[0,1,2,3,4], keep_default_na=False, na_values=['NA'])
print (df)
   0  1  2     3    4
0  a  b  c  NULL  1.0
1  e  f  g     h  2.0
2  j  k  l     m  NaN

for i in df[3]:
    print (type(i), i)
<class 'str'> NULL
<class 'str'> h
<class 'str'> m

for i in df[4]:
    print (type(i), i)
<class 'numpy.float64'> 1.0
<class 'numpy.float64'> 2.0
<class 'numpy.float64'> nan
```

Comment: This is to be done after initialization right? It's a minor issue but it deforms the `NULL` to `nan` =(