# How to treat NULL as a normal string with pandas?

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a csv-file with a column with strings and I want to read it with pandas. In this file the string `null` occurs as an actual value and should not be regarded as a missing value.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = u'strings,numbers\nfoo,1\nbar,2\nnull,3'
print(pd.read_csv(StringIO(data)))
```

This gives the following output:

```
  strings  numbers
0     foo        1
1     bar        2
2     NaN        3
```

What can I do to get the value `null` as it is (and not as NaN) into the DataFrame? The file can be assumed to not contain any actually missing values.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. It gives me `null` as a string.

Comment: @HarvIpan when I run their code, it gives NaN as OP says though... hmm

Comment: @coldspeed, interesting..! I wonder what am I doing wrong. Anyway, yours is a good answer. ~+1.

Comment: I use pandas 0.23.0 with python 3.5.2, if that helps...

Comment: @coldspeed, Fyi, I've reversed the dups, this question now target for [this old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44128033/pandas-reading-null-as-a-nan-float-instead-of-str). Same question, but the answers here are now probably better.

Comment: Try a triple-quoted string to create a multiline string, instead of all those `\n`s.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can specify a `converters` argument for the `string` column.

```
pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), converters={'strings' : str})

  strings  numbers
0     foo        1
1     bar        2
2    null        3
```

This will by-pass pandas' automatic parsing.

---

Another option is setting `na_filter=False`:

```
pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), na_filter=False)

  strings  numbers
0     foo        1
1     bar        2
2    null        3
```

This works for the entire DataFrame, so use with caution. I recommend first option if you want to surgically apply this to select columns instead.

Answer (score 16):

The reason this happens is that the string `'null'` is treated as `NaN` on parsing, you can turn this off by passing `keep_default_na=False` in addition to @coldspeed's answer:

```
In[49]:
data = u'strings,numbers\nfoo,1\nbar,2\nnull,3'
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), keep_default_na=False)
df

Out[49]: 
  strings  numbers
0     foo        1
1     bar        2
2    null        3
```

The full list is:

> na_values : scalar, str, list-like, or dict, default None
>
> Additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN. If dict passed, specific
>   per-column NA values. By default the following values are interpreted
>   as NaN: ‘’, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’,
>   ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘n/a’, ‘nan’,
>   ‘null’.

Comment: Interesting that they have multiple arguments to do the exact same thing...

Comment: @coldspeed yeah the fact you have different side effects depend on whether `na_values` is specified or not further complicates things

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE:** 2020-03-23 for Pandas 1+:

many thanks to [@aiguofer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683765/how-to-treat-null-as-a-normal-string-with-pandas/50684174#comment107609215_50684174) for the adapted solution:

```
na_vals = pd.io.parsers.STR_NA_VALUES.difference({'NULL','null'})
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), na_values=na_vals, keep_default_na=False)
```

---

**Old answer:**

we can dynamically exclude `'NULL'` and `'null'` from the set of default `_NA_VALUES`:

```
In [4]: na_vals = pd.io.common._NA_VALUES.difference({'NULL','null'})

In [5]: na_vals
Out[5]:
{'',
 '#N/A',
 '#N/A N/A',
 '#NA',
 '-1.#IND',
 '-1.#QNAN',
 '-NaN',
 '-nan',
 '1.#IND',
 '1.#QNAN',
 'N/A',
 'NA',
 'NaN',
 'n/a',
 'nan'}
```

and use it in `read_csv()`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), na_values=na_vals)
```

Comment: Thanks! this almost works, but you also need `keep_default_na=False`, and now the default values are in `pd.io.parsers.STR_NA_VALUES`

Comment: @aiguofer, thanks a lot for pointing this out! I've changed the answer accordingly)

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are better for reading in a csv without "null" being interpreted as `Nan`, but if you have a dataframe that you want "fixed", this code will do so: `df=df.fillna('null')`