# Pandas read file containing nan and null as strings

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading in a tab-separated .txt file as a pandas dataframe. In that file, I have entries such as:

```
user1   2013    02  12  10
nan 2013    02  12  10 
null    2013    03  05  6
```

I read in the file like this:

```
with open('usernames_2013.txt', 'r') as f:
    df3 = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', header=None)
    df3.columns=["ID", "Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour"]
```

and I get the following:

```
               ID  Year  Month  Day  Hour
170667  user1  2013      2   12    10
         ID  Year  Month  Day  Hour
170668  NaN  2013      2   12    10
         ID  Year  Month  Day  Hour
262842  NaN  2013      3    5     6
```

I used this code to get those rows:

```
print(payload3.loc[[170667]])
print(payload3.loc[[170668]])
print(payload3.loc[[262842]])
```

So user1 is in row 170667, nan is in row 170668, and null is in row 262842. There are multiple instances of nan and null in the file, this is just an example.

I want `nan` and `null` to both be valid strings; they should not be `NaN`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50683801/4909087), add argument `na_filter=False`.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I didn't see that it was a duplicate.